# Convert the field names in a unlimited depth tree using Jolt

Tags: json, treeview, jolt

Can someone please help with Jolt transformation taking the following into consideration

1. No limitation on the depth of children array, i.e though the example below shows a maximum depth on 2 levels Adam -> John -> Sarah this hierarchy can extend to any level
2. Rename name -> childname, title -> childtitle if the node is present in children array in the hierarchy

Input:

```
{
"person": "Adam",
"personTitle": "MR",
"children": [
    {
        "name": "John",
        "title": "MR",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Sarah",
                "title": "MR",
                "children": [
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Jimmy",
        "title": "MR",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Stephen",
                "title": "MR",
                "children": [
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Output:

```
{
    "person": "Adam",
    "personTitle": "MR",
    "children": [
        {
            "childname": "John",
            "childtitle": "MR",
            "children": [
                {
                    "childname": "Sarah",
                    "childtitle": "MR",
                    "children": [
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "childname": "Jimmy",
            "childtitle": "MR",
            "children": [
                {
                    "childname": "Stephen",
                    "childtitle": "MR"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to do unlimited deep exploration with Jolt. I see two solutions: (1) set a sufficiently but limited depth with the jolt specification or (2) use the recursivity of a programming language (without jolt).

For solution 2, I solved a problem this way:

```java
package kapia.gbo.JsonProcessing;

import java.util.function.Function;

public interface JsonProcessing<T,R> {

    /**
     * In the {@code json}, rename all {@code key} attributes to {@code newKey} then apply the {@code function} with the
     * old value linked to {@code key} as input and returns the new value linked to {@code newKey}.
     * 
     * @param json     to transform
     * @param key      to search and delete
     * @param newKey   to insert with the value returning by {@code function}
     * @param function with {@code T} the type of old value {@code R} the type of new value
     * @return json as String after transformation
     */
    public String apply(String json, String key, String newKey, Function<T,R> function);

}
```

```java
package kapia.gbo.JsonProcessing;

import java.util.function.Function;

import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

public class JsonProcessingWithGsonImpl implements kapia.gbo.JsonProcessing.JsonProcessing<JsonElement,JsonElement> {

    public JsonProcessingWithGsonImpl() {
    }

    public String apply(String json, String key, String newKey, Function<JsonElement, JsonElement> function) {
        JsonElement jsonElement = JsonParser.parseString(json).getAsJsonObject();

        if (jsonElement.isJsonObject()) {
            apply((JsonObject) jsonElement, key, newKey, (Function<JsonElement, JsonElement>) function);
        }

        return jsonElement.toString();
    }

    private void apply(JsonObject jsonObject, String key, String newKey,
            Function<JsonElement, JsonElement> function) {
        if (jsonObject.has(key)) {
            JsonElement value = jsonObject.get(key);
            jsonObject.remove(key);
            jsonObject.add(newKey, function.apply(value));

        }

        // recursive exploration
        for (String currentKey : jsonObject.keySet()) {
            JsonElement element = jsonObject.get(currentKey);
            if (element.isJsonObject()) {
                apply((JsonObject) element, key, newKey, function);
            } else if (element.isJsonArray()) {
                apply((JsonArray) element, key, newKey, function);
            }
        }
    }

    private void apply(JsonArray jsonArray, String key, String newKey,
            Function<JsonElement, JsonElement> function) {
        for (JsonElement element : jsonArray) {
            if (element.isJsonObject()) {
                apply((JsonObject) element, key, newKey, function);
            } else if (element.isJsonArray()) {
                apply((JsonArray) element, key, newKey, function);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test :

```java
package kapia.gbo.JsonProcessing;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONAssert;

import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive;

public class AppTest {

    private JsonProcessing<JsonElement, JsonElement> jsonParser = new JsonProcessingWithGsonImpl();

    private final String JSON_03_INPUT = """
            {
              "policies": {
                "insured": [
                  {
                    "addressType": 6,
                    "partyRef": "REF01",
                    "partyOrder": 1
                  },
                  {
                    "addressType": 6,
                    "partyRef": "REF02",
                    "partyOrder": 2
                  }
                ],
                "subscribers": [
                  {
                    "addressType": 6,
                    "partyRef": "REF01",
                    "partyOrder": 1
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
                        """;

    private final String JSON_03_EXPECTED = "{\"policies\":{\"insured\":[{\"addressType\":6,\"partyId\":1,\"partyOrder\":1},{\"addressType\":6,\"partyId\":2,\"partyOrder\":2}],\"subscribers\":[{\"addressType\":6,\"partyId\":1,\"partyOrder\":1}]}}";

    /**
     * Replace all partyRef with the corresponding partyId.
     * 
     * @throws JSONException
     */
    @Test
    public void test_03() throws JSONException {
        Function<JsonElement, JsonElement> fonction = ancienneValeur -> {
            Map<String, Integer> parties = Map.of("REF01", 1, "REF02", 2);
            String ancienneValeurAsString = (ancienneValeur.isJsonPrimitive()) ? ancienneValeur.getAsString() : null;
            return new JsonPrimitive(parties.get(ancienneValeurAsString));
        };
        String jsonAfter = jsonParser.apply(JSON_03_INPUT, "partyRef", "partyId", fonction);
        JSONAssert.assertEquals(JSON_03_EXPECTED, jsonAfter, false);
    }
}
```